# Eclipse Jeeeyul Chrome Theme: CSS for background

Tags: css, eclipse, themes

I am trying to edit my colour scheme for Eclipse. (Windows!)
I seem to be unable to change the following white areas in the image below.

I know the following code works for certain areas:

```
.MPart Tree, .MPart Table{
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
}
```

If anybody could redirect me to a website containing everything css property or post some code I would be thankful!

The windows I want changed are the ones below in white!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those white areas are governed by source code styling. Easiest way to change them is to use other plugin like Eclipse Color Theme. If you want to create your own theme you can modify a theme file or use http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/

You can also change them manually using Window -> Preferences and then Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring.